# Surjectivity of functions

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $f \colon A \to B$ and $g \colon B \to C$ be two functions.

I proved that if $g \circ f$ is surjective, then so is $g$. I'm thinking about the converse statement, i.e., if $g$ is surjective, then $g \circ f$ needs to be surjective?

Comment: No, for example let $f$ be constant and $C$ have at least $2$ elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathbb R=A=B=C$, $f\colon\mathbb R\to\mathbb R $ is the constant map $f(\mathbb R)=c$, and $g\colon\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is the identity map which is clearly surjective. But $g\circ f$ is not surjective.

Comment: If we assume that functions are group homomorphisms, then can we find a counterexample again?

Comment: @DiegoLópezRodríguez Any example with $f\colon A\to B$ nonsurjective and $g$ the identity over $B$ will do. You can choose $A$ and $B$ to be groups, monoids, rings or whatever and $f$ a homomorphism.

Answer (score 3):

No. Take, for instance, $A=\{0\}$, $B=C=\{0,1\}$, and $f(x)=g(x)=x$. Then $g$ is surjective, but $g\circ f$ is not.